# How to change the tunit from "days" to "months", in variogramST?

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate a Spatio-temporal variogramusing variogramST.
My values are monthly based, means that I have mean monthly data for several locations during the time.
I have made a spatialpoints based on the data and also change the time to POSIXCT format.

My data sample:

```
Year Month  Latitude Longitude    Elev       PC1 Residual                TIME
1 1970     1 -32.63018  115.8229 6.15367 -520.8877 6.810045 1970-01-01 08:00:00
2 1970     1 -32.63000  115.8222 6.28443 -520.8336 6.527605 1970-01-01 08:00:00
3 1970     1 -32.60962  115.8382 6.59723 -520.6321 4.631653 1970-01-01 08:00:00
4 1970     1 -32.60877  115.8785 6.41005 -520.7053 9.817930 1970-01-01 08:00:00
5 1970     1 -32.57639  115.8231 7.20584 -520.2634 1.533665 1970-01-01 08:00:00
6 1970     2 -32.63018  115.8229 6.15367 -520.8877 6.655045 1970-02-01 08:00:00
```

Then I used STIDF function to make a class STIDF file.

But when I try:

```
var <- variogramST(Residual~1,data=timeDF,tunit="hours",na.omit=T) 
plot(var,map=T)
```

It gives me a very weird plot.

```
var <- variogramST(Residual~1,data=timeDF,tunit="hours",na.omit=T)

plot(var,map=F)
plot(var,map=T)
```

I thought maybe the problem is with tunit which should be "months" instead of "hours", but I am not sure and I do not know how to change it.